# vscode extension onDidChangeCursorPosition

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a vscode extention and I want provide something like the bracket match decoration. My problem is that I need to register `onDidChangeCursorPosition` and I don't know how to do that.

My purpose is to create a decorations that appears only when the cursor is on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such event like `onDidChangeCursorPosition`. However you can use [`onDidChangeTextEditorSelection`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#window.onDidChangeTextEditorSelection). The `onDidChangeTextEditorSelection` is actually a field on the vscode's window object and you can assign your own function to it which gets called when this event is sent. Look [at my extension](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/extension.ts#L235) (or many others which do that) to learn how to handle the cursor change event.